# Communicate with external script

Tags: python, subprocess

My python program must reads another program's stdout and sends keys to this program.
I have several questions/answers and it does not work

Here is what i've tried:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['./external_program'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
r = p.communicate() # Reads first question
print(r)
r = p.communicate(input=b'anwer1')[0]   # Sends answer to first question and reads second question
print(r)
...
```

It does not work. Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: can you please upload your `external_program` code?

Comment: Sorry but i do not have this source code but suppose it contains std::cin >> and std::cout <<